# Why my question & it's history was deleted?

Tags: discussion, bug

Recently I request help regarding a problem I'm having with SQL Server instances in a Hyper-V VM. For my surprise, the question was tagged as "off-topic" by a moderator (Tom Tom or Tom O'Connor, I don't remember correctly...) I edited the question, and asked for guindance, since I understand that my question was not off-topic, and it was correctly stated (it has examples of what I did and a nice picture of my environment!).

For what I understand, since I edited the question, it should be reavaliated. But to my surprise, I cannot even SEE the question: it was not closed, it was DELETED, comments & all.

Can someone help me to a) find/recover the question and b) guide me on how to improve it so it can meet the moderator's standards?

Tks!

Answer (score 6):

Your question was closed by the members of our community on 6th May. It was deleted automatically 2 days ago by the Stack Exchange system due to a combination of:

- Being closed
- Having no votes
- Having a very low view count

I will undelete the question as I can see you've put some effort into it, but it will still need to be edited for it to hit the re-open queue to see if it's been improved enough to be on-topic for the site.

Comment: Tks a lot Mark!